# Can't open fragment with constructer. 'Could not find Fragment constructor.'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, uinavigationcontroller

I have fragment called as MoneyListFragment. It is inside a viewpager of HomeFragment. MainAactivity has fragment object in xml. HomeFragment inside it. It open MoneyListFragment to tab layout as view Pager fragment so pass constructor from it.

Now, I want to open MoneyListFragment from MainAcitivty. But I can't get achieve this. I added MoneyListFragment from nav_graph_main.xml. When I tried just like that this error happened.

> Could not find Fragment constructor

How can do this successfully?

nav_graph_main.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/moneyListFragment"
    android:name="com.magazam.ui.earning.money.MoneyListFragment"
    android:label="MoneyListFragment">
    <argument
        android:name="detailList"
        app:argType="com.magazam.adapters.MoneyItem[]" />
    <argument
        android:name="moneyType"
        app:argType="com.magazam.adapters.MoneyType" />
</fragment>



class MoneyListFragment(
    private val detailList: List<MoneyItem>?,
    private val moneyType: MoneyType
) : BaseFragment<FragmentMoneyListBinding>() {

    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> ViewBinding
        get() = FragmentMoneyListBinding::inflate

    override fun onCreateFinished() {
        val detailListFromMain = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<MoneyItem>("detailList")?.toList()
    var moneyTypeFromMain = MoneyType.EARNING
    if(arguments?.getString("moneyType") == MoneyType.EARNING.toString()) moneyTypeFromMain = MoneyType.EARNING
    else if (arguments?.getString("moneyType") == MoneyType.SPENDING.toString()) moneyTypeFromMain = MoneyType.SPENDING

    if (arguments != null){
        if (detailListFromMain.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            binding.groupNoDetail.visible()
        } else {
            binding.rvMoneyDetail.visible()
            binding.rvMoneyDetail.adapter = MoneyDetailAdapter(detailListFromMain, moneyTypeFromMain)
        }
    } else {
        if (detailList.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            binding.groupNoDetail.visible()
        } else {
            binding.rvMoneyDetail.visible()
            binding.rvMoneyDetail.adapter = MoneyDetailAdapter(detailList, moneyType)
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
        if (earningList == null){
            val emptyList = listOf(MoneyItem("null", "null", "null"))
            Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(
                HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeToMoneyListFragment(emptyList.toTypedArray(), MoneyType.SPENDING)
            )
        } else {
            earningList?.let { it1 ->
                Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(
                    HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeToMoneyListFragment(it1.toTypedArray(), MoneyType.SPENDING)
                )
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have `Fragment` with empty contructor and pass the parameter as arguments in a bundle.
Since you have a list it wouldn't be good to pass it in the bundle so you should use a VM that keeps the list and maybe the `moneyType` param too.